# How to fix Veins5.2 Build Errors with Omnet++ 6.0?

Tags: omnet++

I imported Veins5.2 into Omnet++ 6.0 on Windows and when building it shows the following build Error :

---

Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_dbg.dll

ld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) WSAGetLastError

> > > referenced by ////omnetpp-6.0/omnetpp-6.0/include/omnetpp/platdep/sockets.h:33
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(sock_errno())

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) WSAStartup

> > > referenced by ////omnetpp-6.0/omnetpp-6.0/include/omnetpp/platdep/sockets.h:47
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(initsocketlibonce())
> > > referenced by ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) closesocket

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:87
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::~TraCIConnection())
> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:127
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))
> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:152
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) inet_addr

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:103
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) gethostbyname

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:107
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) htons

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:119
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) socket

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:124
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))
> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:129
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) connect

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:126
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) setsockopt

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:147
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::connect(omnetpp::cComponent*, char const*, int))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) recv

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:188
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::receiveMessageabi:cxx11)
> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:210
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::receiveMessageabi:cxx11)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) send

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:237
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::sendMessage(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >))
> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc:253
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.o:(veins::TraCIConnection::sendMessage(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) htonl

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:138
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) bind`your text`

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:141
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) getsockname

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:146
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) ntohs

> > > referenced by veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc:150
> > > ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.o:(veins::TraCIScenarioManagerForker::getPortNumber() const)
> > > collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> > > \\omnetpp-6.0\omnetpp-6.0\tools\win32.x86_64\mingw64\bin/llvm-ar.exe: error: unable to load '../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_dbg.dll.a': No such file or directory
> > > make[1]: *** [Makefile:217: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libveins_dbg.dll] Error 1
> > > make[1]: Leaving directory '///// veins-veins-5.2/veins-veins-5.2/src'
> > > make: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2
> > > "make MODE=debug -j16 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Build Failed. 2 errors, 2 warnings. (took 36s.395ms)

Cleaned local , cleane build, still has the same issue

Comment: You are most likely trying to build on a non-working combination of OMNeT++, Veins, and Windows. See http://veins.car2x.org/download/#compatibility for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had build errors also when trying to get Veins running with OMNet++ 6.0 on Windows.  See the changelog here:  http://veins.car2x.org/download/.  Veins lists recommended versions and recommends OMNet++ 5.6.2 instead of 6.0.  I had no build errors when using the recommended versions. Good luck!